# You got last 3 bites

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

He haven't done eating.

There are 3 more spoons of rice.

> "You got last 3 bites."
>
> "You got last 3 spoons."

As the context above, can I use bite to imply 1 spoon of rice?
[image: plate with a spoon full of rice and some rice on the plate]

Comment: Both sentences need "the". And whether "bites" can be used here; I'm not sure if that depends on how sticky the rice is.

Comment: *Spoons* literally means just "the eating device that we call a spoon", so I think you want the word *spoonfuls*.  Also, it's bad form to say "You got"; say "You *have*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You got last" is not idiomatic.

> You have three bites left.
>
> You have three bites remaining.

We wouldn't use **bites** with rice or peas or any similar food that consists of small bits.  We'd say "spoonfuls" instead.

> You have three spoonfuls of rice left.

A few people would say "spoonsful" instead of "spoonfuls".

Comment: Could I say "Three more to go"?

Comment: Yes, "to go" in that context is another way of saying "remaining".  *He was almost finished school for the year. There were only two more exams to go.*